# Defining __init__ using lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, lambda, constructor

I know that we can define class functions like so :

```
pp = lambda self,v: self.list[v]
```

but I am struggling with the syntax for defining the constructor the same way :

```
__init__ = lambda self: self.list = []
```

I googled around why this is not working but seems like nobody was crazy enough to try this. Folks who are knowledgeable in python internals, could you please help me understand why this is not working?

For people asking why do I want to do it this way -
Just for the fun of coding and more knowledge, it would feel pretty amazing if it can be done somehow.

Axe answered it beautifully and I used it to solve a leetcode question -
https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/discuss/2474150/BRUTALLY-OPTMISED-Python-Solution

Comment: Is there a reason you want to declare `__init__` this way? lambdas are great for anonymous functions but it doesn't make sense to me to declare a class constructor this way.

Comment: Just for the fun of coding, it would look pretty amazing if it can be done

Comment: @Axe319: I think you mean "because `self.list = []` **isn't** an expression."

Comment: Thanks @Axe319, this works, if you can put this in ans, I can accept

Comment: Just to reiterate what Axe319 said, you shouldn't do this in practice. It may "look cool" but it is an antipattern.

Comment: Can anyone explain why it shouldn't be used in practice? @h0r53

Comment: Reasons I wouldn't use it are: It saves at the most, 1 line at the cost of making things less clear.  Using `setattr` means it makes refactoring harder if you ever want to rename the attribute. Most importantly, it's not what someone would typically see, so reading it is going to take more time than the *explicit* version.

Comment: @Axe319 makes sense, I agree with your points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: *This should not be done in production code unless you want your coworkers to hate you.*

A `lambda` is just a single line function with *only* an implicit `return` statement.

So your first example `pp = lambda self,v: self.list[v]` could be rewritten as:

```
def pp(self,v):
    return self.list[v]
```

Doing so for your second example, `__init__ = lambda self: self.list = []` would result in this:

```
def __init__(self):
    return self.list = []
```

This isn't valid python syntax as `self.list = []` isn't an expression and holds no value in itself.

You could use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) which DOES `return` something, `None`.

```
__init__ = lambda self: setattr(self, 'list', [])
```

Rewritten as an actual method:

```
def __init__(self):
    return setattr(self, 'list', [])
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on using lambda for function definitions instead of the standard def? Are there any cases where defining function using lambda (thereby removing the anonymity) is preferable?

Comment: @namanjain lambas aren't meant for this. Lambdas are used as an anonymous function definition. When considering OOP, public methods of objects should be well defined. Lambdas are great for things such as callbacks, not a proper class method.